# Synonym for subscribe

Tags: synonyms

I am developing a software in which I use the following terms:

- `subscriber`
- `publisher`
- `subscription`

When a subscriber subscribes to a topic, something like this happens:

```
subscription = subscriber.subscribe(publisher)
```

I am struggling with the proper word when I subscribe from the aspect of the publisher:

```
subscription = publisher.properWord(subscriber)
```

I thought of `relay`, but it simply does not mean the same. It should have an opposite as well. It is `unsubscribe` by `subscribe`, but there is no `derelay`...

So what does the publisher do with the subscriber when they create a new subscription?

Comment: essentially, it doesn't matter who *signs you up* for your newspaper subscription, the fact of the matter is that you are subscribed.  i'd use the same word.

Comment: Maybe "register"?

Comment: I think a description of the publisher's action or status change is what's wanted.

Comment: @JimReynolds Exactly. The topic does not subscribe on the subscriber... So it has to be a different word then subscribe. The register is not a very specific word, I don't like to use it. I usually start with register when I address similar issues and I mostly override it later when I have found the proper topic specific words... (So yes I have already used register. After that I overrode it with addSubscriber which is still not good enough to me.)

Comment: I don't think there's a single word for it. I'd say the publisher _processes the subscription_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there's a specific word. An alternative to register is *enroll,* though *addSubscriber* seems pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks! `Enroll` is a nice word. `Recruit`, `enlist` are good as well. I think I'll stay with `enlist` and `unenlist`...